# Correct algorithm to execute an ordered sequence of task which are done by several threads

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing, pthreads

I'm currently programming an algorithm where a main thread Thread_0 manage a pool of thread {Thread_1,Thread_2,...,Thread_m} that are used to execute an ordered sequence of tasks {Task_1,Task_2,Task_3,...,Taskn}. Each task Task_i is executed by all threads Tread_i i>0, and the conclusion of the Task_i by each thread is the necessary and sufficient condition of the execution of the Task_i+1. My problem is with the synchronization between the pool of threads and the main thread.
First, when each thread is created, the main thread must wait for the initialization of each thread before creating the next one, because the data pointed by pointer passed to the thread function must be copied by the thread before its content is modified. Once all threads ara initialized, the main thread must compute some values which are necessary for execute Task_0, and the other threads must wait for a broadcasted signal to start with  Task_0. Once Task_0 is completed, the main thread must
must compute other values which are necessary for execute Task_1, and the other threads must wait for a broadcasted signal to start with  Task_1. And so on.

My questions are the following:

1. Have this algorithm/problem a specific name?
2. It seems that is common for waiting for thread initialization,
   there is an standard procedure for that?
3. This kind of algorithm must be implement using barriers?
4. I have an idea to solve this problem usign a mutex for each thread,
   but I want to avoid this.
5. I have tried to solve this with two condition variable cv0 and cv1, and one mutex mx0, but this avoid threads to work in parallel:

   ```
   void* worker(void* data_in){
     lock mx0
     copy input data
     flag=1
     signal cv0
     wait for condition signal cv1 with mx0
     // Initialize Task 0
     read DataForTask0
     // do Task_0
     flag=1
     signal cv0
     wait for condition signal cv1 with mx0
     // Initialize Task_1
     //...
     //...
   }

   int main(){
     flag=0
     for(i=0;i<TNum;i++){
       lock mx0  
       data=CurrentValue(i);
       pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,worker,(void*)&data);
       while(!flag0)
         wait for condition sigal cv0 with mx0
       flag=0
       unlock mx0
     }
     // Here all threads must be waithing for cv1
     lock mx0
     Initialize DataForTask0
     broadcast cv1
     counter=0
     do{
       flag=0
       while(!flag0)
         wait for condition signal cv0 with mx0
       counter++
     }while(counter<TNum)
     //...  
   }
   ```

Comment: Your not making much sense.... or not explaining what you are trying to achieve. 1. Can the tasks run the parallel? 2.is the some kind of requirement that some task must wait on others, if so then you need to factor this in your programming.... more complicated than just an order. for me it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Thread queue.. with order... but have dependencies.... you need to manage the dependencies then and tell threads to wait. but why not just execute in 1 thread then?

Comment: This sounds like a pretty useless application for multithreading. Apparently, the easiest thing to do fulfilling all requirements is: Put everything into the main thread.

Comment: Dear@Seabizkit, All task must run in parallel, and they only need to wait for the main thread to process some stuff before execute the next task.  Yes, there is an ordered queue with dependence, but each task is executed by several threads. Dear @tofro, I wish to implement an agreement algorithm between machines; This represents a client that has to communicate with several unreliable servers, which less than half, may crash. Because waiting for answers of these serves blocks the thread, and you don't know if any will response, each communication channel must run in parallel.

Comment: @RafaelRojas Waiting for answers does not need to necessarily block a thread - Using async I/O might help. And might be much more lightweight than putting up a number of threads.

Comment: @tofro, I got your point. Thank you. But listening is not the only task of each thread,  other stuff is done for each specific server.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what is your goal. Have a look at the [pipeline model](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169479&seqNum=5) and see if that is what you want. Basically, in a pipeline model, you have n independent tasks, each with m ordered steps. You want to process them on multiple threads. TBB implements a pipeline model in C++. [Here](http://attractivechaos.github.io/klib/#Kthread%3A%20simple%20threading%20models) is another implementation in C, but it is not very easy to use.